# PHP /= calculation issue

Tags: php

When i write this whole code

```
<?php
        $var1=3;  
    ?>

    <br/>

    <?php $var1 += 4; echo $var1; ?>  
    <?php $var1 -= 4; echo $var1; ?>  
    <?php $var1 *= 4; echo $var1; ?> 
    <?php $var1 /= 4; echo $var1; ?> 

    <br/>
```

It gives me results like this. Result of division is not right here (last one).
7
3
12
3
But when i just use

```
 <?php
        $var1=3;  
    ?>

    <br/>

    <?php $var1 /= 4; echo $var1; ?> 

    <br/>
```

Now it gives me correct result for division, which is "0.75". why is that so?

Comment: do you *know* what `+=` actually does? it's the same as `$var1= $var1+4`. meaning, after your first line, $var1 IS 7, after the second 3, after the third 12. and 12 divided by four again is three.

Comment: `var1` before division is `12`. Your `echo` shows it. `12/4 = 3`.

Comment: thanks a lot. i knew what it does but  i don't know was that the value is actually combining with lower ones also.

Answer (score 0):

in your code value of $var1 changed in each step.
Try this:

```
<?php $var1=3; ?>

<?php echo $var1+4; ?><br/>
<?php echo $var1-4; ?><br/>
<?php echo $var1*4; ?><br/>
<?php echo $var1/4; ?><br/>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the first example you multiply $var1 by 4 before dividing it by 4, putting $var1 back at 3.

In the second example, you divide 3 by 4.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15141979)

Comment: @arghtype The last sentence of the question is "why is that so?" My answer is neither a critique nor a request for qualification. It is an answer to the question.